# how to impliment Search particular record from .json file using angular2

Tags: json, angular, search

What I need to do is when i enters text inside `textbox` , i need to filter result inside li

I need do same as [here](https://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/02/07/live-search-using-custom-filter-in-angular-js/)
but this is done using `ajax` and i need to do using `angular2` with data loading from `.json` file

my `index.html` is

```
<div id="search-container">
  <div class="search" id="search-btn"></div>
  <input #searchBox id="search" type="text" name="search-input"          (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)">
  <ul class="data-ctrl">
     <li ng-repeat="i in items >i[0].name</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My `app.component.ts` is

```
constructor(public http: Http,public _dmcService: DmcService) {
    this._dmcService.getData('prc').subscribe(
        data => { this.listingval= "prc"; this.assignJson(data); }
    );
  }
```

`assignJson` function from `app.component.ts`:
here i assigned data to heroes which is loaded from json file

```
assignJson(data: any) {
    displayContent= data.teacher[0].libraryItems;
     for (var i = 0; i <displayContent.length; i++) {
       this.heroes[i] = [
      { id: i, name: data.teacher[0].libraryItems[i].display_title.slice(30)}
      ];
     }
}
```

`dmc.service.ts`:

```
getData(filename: string) {
        return this.http.get('assets/data/' + filename + '.json').map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

`prc.json`:

```
{
  "isbn": "9781328694829",
  "teacher": [
    {
      "component": "Core Resources",
      "libraryItems": [
        {
          "id": "9781328694829-00001",
          "display_title": "Practice- Ungroup from the Left or from the Right"
        },
        {
          "id": "9781328694829-00002",
          "display_title": "Reteach- Ungroup from the Left or from the Right",
        }
      ]
     }
}
```

`search` function in `app.component.ts`:

```
 search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

 ngOnInit(): void {
    let heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;
    this.heroes = this.searchTerms
      .debounceTime(300)        // wait for 300ms pause in events
      .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
      .switchMap(term => term   // switch to new observable each time
        // return the http search observable
        ? this.heroSearchService.search(term)
        // or the observable of empty heroes if no search term
        : Observable.of<Hero[]>([]))
      .catch(error => {
        // TODO: real error handling
        console.log(error); 
        return Observable.of<Hero[]>([]);
      });
  }
```

my `heroesSearchService` is as

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroSearchService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  search(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
   console.log('term:: ',term);
   var str  =  this.http.get(`app/heroes/?name=${term}`)
               .map((r: Response) => r.json().data as Hero[]);
    return str;
  }
}
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

my current code not working, can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: you are loading data via `this.http.get('assets/data/' + filename + '.json').map((res: Response) => res.json());`  ?

Comment: @anshuVersatile my data is loading fine from JSON but i am not able to impliment autocomplete using jQuery in Angular 2 rc4,   can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396142/how-to-use-jquery-autocomplete-in-angular-2-rc4