# How to use jQuery autocomplete in angular 2 rc4

Tags: jquery, angular, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use jQuery autocomplete in angular 2 rc4 version but i am getting error as 'property autocomplete does not exist on type jquery'

My HTML is :

```html
<input class="search" id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
```

& my app.component.ts is

```js
heroes:any = [100,200,101];
ngOnInit(): void { 
  jQuery( "#search-input" ).autocomplete({
    source: this.heroes
  });
}
```

expected result should be when i enter 1 in input box then 100 and 101 should pop up and i can move along result using arrow keys.

I already installed JQuery typings as my other jQuery functionsworks well and i also tried to use solution from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ang2-autocomplete, but i think its for another versions of angular rc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using AngularJS 1 
Please refer [AutoComplete](https://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/) this website reference. It will be better use AngularJS completely instead of jQuery.

For AngularJS2 use [AutoComplete](https://github.com/ng2-ui/ng2-auto-complete)